# How can I get my function params using generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have many namespaces with many methods, I want to get method params when `dispatch` by action type. My code is:

```
interface RouterAction {
  type: 'router-action';
}

type DispatchRouterAction = (action: RouterAction) => any;

interface InterfaceEffects {
  firstMethod(data: { payload: { test: '456' } }): any;
  secondMethod(data: { payload: number }): any;
}

type ReplaceStr<Str extends string, Split extends string> = Str extends `${infer Prefix}${Split}${infer Suffix}`
  ? `${ReplaceStr<Prefix, Prefix>}${Suffix}`
  : Str;

type ActionTypeList = 'myNamespace/firstMethod' | 'myNamespace/secondMethod';

type DispatchDvaAction = (action: { type: ActionTypeList; payload?: any; [key: string]: any }) => any;

type TypeDispatch<D> = D extends (action: infer Action) => any
  ? Action extends { type: infer ActionType }
    ? ActionType extends ActionTypeList
      ? (action: {
          type: ActionTypeList;
          payload: Parameters<InterfaceEffects[ReplaceStr<ActionType, '/'>]>[0]['payload'];
        }) => any
      : DispatchRouterAction
    : DispatchRouterAction
  : DispatchRouterAction;

type DispatchCustom = TypeDispatch<DispatchDvaAction>;

const dispatchA = (dispatch: DispatchCustom) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'myNamespace/secondMethod', payload: 123 });
};
```

I think this codes should work but it did not.

TS tell me payload is num & {test:'456'}

So how can I do this？

Comment: This code is pretty complex and it's not clear which parts you're allowed to change and which parts you need to keep.  If `InterfaceEffects` needs to stay the same then maybe I'd write it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/WG2dJm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks fou your help, In my example code I only show you one namesapce named 'myNamespace', but there are many another namespace like `anotherNamespace/anotherNamespaceMethod`. Thanks again

Comment: If you want the solution to support other things you need to show examples; where are these namespaces and method names coming from?  Are they random?  Are they in a list?  Are they programmatically determined from something?  I can make it support arbitrary namespace prefixes like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6xz6m), but without more information it's hard to know how to proceed.  Please [edit] the question to demonstrate examples covering the range of things you need to support.